Match JSX/HTML tags in neovim pattern
I'm trying to configure a plugin action to find JSX tags as a pattern. I'm not quite sure how to use patterns. Is it a regular regex or some specific nvim regex engine?
This is the regex I wan't to implement: https://regex101.com/r/eeGrej/1
<([a-zA-Z1-6]+)([^<]+)*(?:>(.*)<\/\1>|\s+\/>)


Patterns are described here, comparing them with perl  in this section, but you'll want to read the whole page.

Obligatory reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 regarding parsing HTML with regex.

([^<]+)* doesn't make sense, [^<]* is the same thing and more efficient. Moreover it prevents catastrophic backtracking
